# MongoDB/Mongoose CastError: Cast to string failed for value (type Object) at path "field"

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I'm encountering an issue with my Node.js application using MongoDB and Mongoose. I have a schema defined in Mongoose with an array field, and I'm trying to insert data into it. However, I keep getting a "CastError" with the message "Cast to string failed for value" even though I'm sending an object.

Here is the schema

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";

const contentSchema = new Schema(
    {
        chapter_id: String,
        videos: [
            {
                title: String,
                url: String,
                type: String,
                thumbnail: String,
                status: String,
            },
        ],
        notes: [
            {
                title: String,
                url: String,
                type: String,
            },
        ],
        materials: [
            {
                title: String,
                url: String,
                type: String,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);

const Content =
    mongoose.models.Content || mongoose.model("Content", contentSchema);

export default Content;
```

ThunderClient Request

```
{
    "title": "sdsadasd",
    "url": "dsadasd",
    "type": "paid",
    "status": "public",
    "thumbnail": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/imdad-library.appspot.com/o/videos%2F1694854998003?alt=media&token=6b62c9cb-74d9-4720-8743-532e5ce2d843",
    "chapter_id": "6504b3479d1c0bb266ee8353"
}
```

Backend Code

```
import connectMongoDB from "@/lib/mongodb";
import Content from "@/models/content";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(request) {
    try {
        await connectMongoDB();
        const { title, url, type, thumbnail, status, chapter_id } = await request.json();

        let chapter = await Content.findOne({ chapter_id });
        if (!chapter) {
            chapter = await Content.create({ chapter_id, videos: [], notes: [], materials: [] });
        }

        const existingVideo = chapter.videos.find((video) => video.title === title && video.url === url);

        if (existingVideo) {
            return NextResponse.json({ message: "Video already exists in this chapter" }, { status: 400 });
        }

        chapter.videos.push({ title, url, type, thumbnail, status });
        await chapter.save();

        return NextResponse.json({ message: "Course created successfully" }, { status: 200 });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return NextResponse.json({ error: 'An error occurred while creating course' }, { status: 500 });
    }
}
```

The error

```
"Cast to string failed for value \"{\n  title: 'dsad',\n  url: 'dsad',\n  type: 'paid',\n  thumbnail: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/imdad-library.appspot.com/o/videos%2F1694877460547?alt=media&token=a04c6df1-f66e-4faa-b246-6897c936aa12',\n  status: 'public'\n}\" (type Object) at path \"videos\""
```

I've tried various solutions, including verifying the schema, checking the front-end request, and confirming my MongoDB Atlas setup. Despite these checks, I still encounter the "CastError." I've also ensured that the JSON data sent from the front end is correctly structured.

I appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `type` is a special property in mongoose schemas. See [the documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#type-key) for details. (The amount of questions here on SO that could be answered from people just reading the documentation for the libs they use are astoundingly high)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating schema with following and give a try

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from "mongoose";

const contentSchema = new Schema(
  {
    chapter_id: String,
    videos: [
      {
        title: { type: String },
        url: { type: String },
        type: { type: String },
        thumbnail: { type: String },
        status: { type: String },
      },
    ],
    notes: [
      {
        title: { type: String },
        url: { type: String },
        type: { type: String },
      },
    ],
    materials: [
      {
        title: { type: String },
        url: { type: String },
        type: { type: String },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const Content =
  mongoose.models.Content || mongoose.model("Content", contentSchema);

export default Content;
```

Comment: It's enough to use the `{ type: String }` notation for the `type` property only. No need to change all of them. You should also add an explanation as to *why* this is the case to make this answer complete.